# What is the name of this syntax?

Tags: c

Recently, I am reading some source code. I found one syntax I haven't seen before. Also can't found any clue.

```cpp
#define v(t, s, name, ...)                                              \
..
    name.size = sizeof((__typeof__(name.buf[0])[]){0, __VA_ARGS__}) /   \
                    sizeof(name.buf[0]) - 1;
```

Let me modify this macro into **real** statement:

```cpp
int a[20];
printf("%d",sizeof((__typeof__(a[0])[]){0,2,4,5})/sizeof(a[0]) - 1);
```

I wondering how do we call the syntax like `(int[ ]){1,2,3....}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is called [a compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).